# How to initialize an empty 2-dimensional array in Julia?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

```
m = []
```

initializes an empty array of dimension 1. I want to initialize an empty array of dimension 2 (to which I'll append values later on). Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### As of Julia 1.8

It's now much simpler to [create empty arrays](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/41618):

> Empty *n*-dimensional arrays can now be created using multiple semicolons inside square brackets.

```py
julia> m = [;;]
# 0×0 Matrix{Any}
```

```py
julia> m = [;;;]
# 0×0×0 Array{Any, 3}
```

---

Note that this is just syntactic sugar for constructing an uninitialized [`Array`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Core.Array-Tuple%7BUndefInitializer,%20Any%7D):

> [`julia/test/syntax.jl#L3143-L3146`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/5544a0fab7648cfa61fe79cd557a7504a92ec1b5/test/syntax.jl#L3143-L3146)
>
> ```matlab
> @test []    == Array{Any}(undef, 0)
> @test [;]   == Array{Any}(undef, 0)
> @test [;;]  == Array{Any}(undef, 0, 0)
> @test [;;;] == Array{Any}(undef, 0, 0, 0)
> ```

Comment: This creates a 0x2 Matrix. But when assigning values to lets say the first column by `gogo=Array{Any}(undef,0,2)` : `gogo[:,1]=go` with `go=ones(6)` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 34):

As of Julia 1.0 you can use:

```
m = Array{Float64}(undef, 0, 0)
```

for an *(0,0)-size* 2-D Matrix storing `Float64` values and more in general:

```
m = Array{T}(undef, a, b, ...,z)
```

for an *(a,b,...,z)-size* multidimensional Tensor (whose content is garbage of type `T`).

Comment: I suggest you replace the `T` by `Float64` in your examples. Otherwise people might copy past and get an error.

Answer (score 15):

Try:

```
m = reshape([],0,2)
```

or,

```
m = Array{Float64}(undef, 0, 2)
```

The second option which explicitly defines type should generate faster code.

A commenter ephemerally suggested using `Matrix()` for a 0x0 matrix and `Matrix(0,2)` for a 0x2 matrix.

Comment: I though that syntax was deprecated and instead one should use `m = Array{Float64, 2}()`.

Comment: All variants seem to work warning-less in both 0.4 and 0.5. But, answer can changed to reflect better practice. Any reference?

Comment: The second one won't work on 1.0 anymore! You should really mention this in your answer. Also, you are missing the suggested way of doing it in 1.0 (see Antonello's answer).